# How can I save a response of HTTP GET Request in variable?

Tags: ajax, http

Here is my API code

```
 @GetMapping("/api/test")
    public String test() {
        return "hello";
    }
```

Then I will send request to this API by using ajax.

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/test",
        success: function(response) {
           
        }
    })
}
```

I want to save the value of ajax call response (In this case "hello") in variable. Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Several ways of doing it !**

1. As far as only a String message is concerned you can just store it like below

   ```
   `var myResponse=response;`
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can also access values if response is an `object (JSON reponse I mean)`

   ```
   for e.g. `var resp=response.message; //Assuming message is a key in response JSON`
   ```
3. For testing,  use `alert(response)` or `console.log(response)` to see how your response is coming and manipulate accordingly !
4. Feel free to refer this link for detailed Ajax walkthrough https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

Hope these helps!